# Is it possible to create a basic bare-metal Assembly bootup/startup program using only GNU LD command-line options

Tags: linker, arm, cortex-m, bare-metal

Is it possible to create a basic bare-metal Assembly bootup/startup program using only GNU LD command-line options in lieu of a customary -T scriptfile for a Cortex-M4 target?

I have reviewed the GNU LD documentation and searched various locations including this site; however, I have not found any information suggesting that the exclusive use of command-line options for the GNU linker is possible or not possible.

My attempt to manage the object file layout without a customary vendor provided *.ld scriptfile is purely academic. This not homework. I'm not requesting any help for writing the startup Assembly code. I'm merely looking for a definitive answer or further resource direction.

```
$ arm-none-eabi-ld bootup.o -o bootup @bootup.ld.cli.file
```

Sample bootup.ld.cli.file content

```
--entry 0x0
--Ttext=0x0
--section-start .isr_vector=0x0
--section-start _start=0x4
--section-start .MyCode=0x8c
--Tdata=0x20000000
--Tbss=0x20000000
-M=bootup.map
--print-gc-sections
```

Comment: You can do this with a linker file (define section data using [output section data](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Data.html) with `BYTE`, `SHORT`, `LONG` and `QUAD`.  You can also have your file be read from stdin so your could use `echo` or other methods to specify everything on the command line.  These statements (`BYTE, SHORT, LONG, QUAD`) are mainly useful to provide header information for some other system loader (maybe SOC rom code).  So it is **possible**, this is not the best route and it is more sensible to use assembler.  You can also import raw binary files.

Comment: @artlessnoise - Yes, thank you. But in the instant case I'm trying to avoid the linker file; at least directly.

Comment: I see, your 'bootup.ld.cli' is a lot like a linker file, but it is not technically.  I thought you didn't want to compile/assemble any code to make a bootable/executeable file.  Your title mislead me.

Comment: @artlessnoise Yes, the *.ld.cli contains the command-line options;however, this is not the customary linker file format. I wish to avoid using the customary linker file format. I'm writing an ARMv7 Assembly bootup/startup code inclusive of vector tables, handlers, and vector table relocation. Sorry for the unclear title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have your answer right there the -Ttext=number -Tdata=number and so on are no gnu linker script items they are gnu command line items. note the at sign on your command line.

A gnu linker script looks more like this (although most are significantly more complicated even if they dont need to be).

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Note that the gnu linker is a bit funny when you use the -Ttext=address approach, sometimes it will insert gaps you might have a few Kbytes of program and instead of it just linearly placing it at address like it should it will put some, then pad some dead space, then put some more, never figured out why but for extremely limited targets the linker script (vs command line) all other factors held constant, does not put the gap in the output.

EDIT:

so.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .
```

flash.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

blinker02.c

```
void dummy ( unsigned int );

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    for(ra=0;ra<100;ra++) dummy(ra);
    return(0);
}
```

Makefile

```
ARMGNU = arm-none-eabi

AOPS = --warn -mcpu=cortex-m0
COPS = -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m0

all : blinker02.bin sols.bin socl.bin

clean:
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.list

so.o : so.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) so.s -o so.o

flash.o : flash.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) flash.s -o flash.o

blinker02.o : blinker02.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -mthumb -c blinker02.c -o blinker02.o

blinker02.bin : flash.ld flash.o blinker02.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker02.elf -T flash.ld flash.o blinker02.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker02.elf > blinker02.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker02.elf blinker02.bin -O binary

sols.bin : so.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o sols.elf -T flash.ld so.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D sols.elf > sols.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy sols.elf sols.bin -O binary

socl.bin : so.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o socl.elf -Ttext=0x08000000 -Tbss=0x20000000 so.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D socl.elf > socl.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy socl.elf socl.bin -O binary
```

The difference between the command line and the linker script socl and sols list files are the names

```
diff sols.list socl.list
2c2
< sols.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm
---
> socl.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm
```

Not going to bother with demonstrating the difference you may see down the road.

For assembly only you dont need to worry about the no start files and other command line options (on gcc).  With C objects you do.  by not allowing the linker to use the as-built/configured toolchains (or lets say C library) bootstrap code, you have to provide one, if you dont complicate the linker script to the point that specific object files are called out then the ordering of objects on the command line matters, if you swap flash.o and blinker02.o on the ld command line in the makefile, the binary wont work.  you can set entry points all you want but those are strictly for the loader, if this is bare metal which it appears to be then the entry point is useless, the hardware boots how it boots, in this case with a cortex-m address zero is the value to load in the stack pointer, address four is the address to the reset vector (with the lsbit set since this is a thumb only machine, let the tools do that for you using the gnu assembler specific thumb_func to indicate the next label is a branch destination address).

I sprinkled cortex-m0 about one because that is what I took this code from and two the original armv4t and armv5t or as called out in the newer arm docs "all thumb variants", is the most portable arm instruction set across the arm cores.  with your cortex-m4 you can get rid of that or perhaps make it a -m3 or -m4 to pull in the armv7-m thumb2 extensions.

so the short answer is

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -o so.elf -Ttext=0x08000000 -Tbss=0x20000000 so.o
```

Is more than adequate for making working binaries ASSUMING you dont need a .data.

.data requires a lot more stuff, linker script, a more complicated bootstrap, etc.  That or you do a copy-jump thing,  compile the REAL program to be run in sram only (different entry point full sized arm style but at the ram base address), then write an adhoc tool to take that binary and turn it into say .word 0xabcdef entries in a program that copies from flash to ram the whole REAL program then branches, that copy and jump program is now flash only with no .data nor .bss really needed and can use the command line, so can the REAL ram only program.  And I probably lost you already on that one.

Likewise, using the command line you cannot or should not assume that .bss is zeroed, your bootstrap has to do that too.  Now if you have .bss and no .data, then sure you could blindly zero all of the ram on boot before you branch to your C programs entry point (I use notmain() both because at least one old compiler added unnecessary garbage to the binary if it saw a main() function and to emphasize the point that normally there is nothing magic about the function named main().).

Linker scripts are toolchain specific, so no reason to expect gnu linker scripts to port to Kiel to port to ARM (yes I know ARM owns Kiel now was referring to RVCT or whatever it is now), etc.  So that is the first .data/.bss problem.  Ideally you want your tools to do the work, so they know how bit .data and .bss are so just let them tell you, how you let them tell you is crafting the linker script right (at least with ld) and that is tricky, but it creates variables if you will that can define things like start address for .bss, end address for .bss maybe even some math to subtract them and get length, likewise for .data, then in the bootstrap assembly language you can zero out the .bss memory using start address and length, and/or start address and end address.  For .data you need two addresses, where you put it in flash (more linker script foo) and where it wants to go in ram, and the length then the bootstrap copies.

so basically if you write this code

```
unsigned int x=5;
unsigned int y;
```

and you use a command line linker script, there is no reason whatsoever to expect x to be 5 or y to be 0 when the first C function is entered that uses those variables.  If you assume that x will be a 5 then your program will fail.

if you do this instead

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
void myfun ( void )
{
   x=5;
   y=0;
}
```

now those assignments are instructions in .text and not values in .data so it will always work command line or not simple linker script or complicated, etc.

Comment: The layout seems fine when viewing via the map file,  objdump, and readelf; however,  I'm not able to step past the ResetHandler.  PC does not advance; which is why I'm asking if a command-line only approach is sufficient for a complete and proper layout.  I will mark your answer accordingly since I think it should work.

Comment: yes absolutely been building with and without linker scripts for years, the primary difference is this gnu ld weirdness...

Comment: you have one object is that assembly language or are you trying to rely on the toolchains bootstrap?  (which wont work without the matching linker script that goes with it).

Comment: I wrote some very bare Assembly startup code derived, in part, from vendor provided files.  So I'm using a single object file; which works well using Code Composer Studio with a customary vendor linker (. cmd) script. So now I'm trying to do this with LD without a customary linker script.

Comment: the edit shows you wont need the ide anymore if you dont want, although if that is your only path to downloading then you have to figure something out.  if this is a formerly luminary micro part (stellaris, now called tiva c) then you can use lmflash instead of CCS to load the program.  Wait you said cortex-m4 so that was after they bought luminary micro.  So this is an MSP432 probably?  My solution is a little hokey, I use openocd (swd) to download programs to ram, then have programs I wrote that can then write stuff to flash.  but I dont use CCS at all.

Comment: Thank you.  I will examine this carefully.

Comment: sure, no problem.

Comment: The target device is a TI TM4C1294 Connected LaunchPad. Connecting with OpenOCD. Able to use LM4Flash. Debugging w/ GDB using target-extended-remote :3333 & (gdb) load <bootfile> command to flash programs.

Comment: Nice, good, just wanted to point out that you dont have to use CCS if you dont want to, particularly if you want to take over more control.  But you may lose out on some of their libraries, or have to at least find and link them, etc...you have more options now that you can control the toolchain directly.